# How to block "Monkey Test " & "Time Service" Malware in android?

Tags: android, antivirus, malware, android-os-handler

Antivirus shows these apps as malware, I tried to uninstall these apps but after sometimes system install these apps automatically. Can anyone suggest how to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use link2sd application to freeze them and then try to uninstall them.

Answer (score -1):

Root your phone, Then follow the below steps.

1. Download and install Lucky Patcher on your device (if your phone is rooted, fine, if it’s not don’t bother).
2. Open Lucky Patcher and select **MonkeyTest** from the list of apps displayed
3. Select **Tools** from the list of menu
4. Then select **Disable Package (Freeze)**.
5. Repeat steps 2 to 4 for **Time Service** and any other auto-installing apps on your device.